# hklm\Security Vs Security\Policy

Tags: windows, internals, sysinternals, lsa

I am researching the way an attacker would get a machine credentials.
I figured the most common methods are to dump

```
hklm\sam
hklm\security 
hklm\system
```

I was able to figure what information is stored in the SAM and why would I want to save it, but wasnt able to figure the difference between the other 2 registries.

I have read many manuals by now, and the explanations for both always seem very similar, so I cant tell what is the difference

Comment: System contains a lot more stuff, hardware and software configuration etc.

Comment: @Anders , Thank you very much.
I think I was able to figure in more depth about the actual diffrences, hope I am right:

LSA secret, stored under HKLM\security and contains cached domain records
.......
syskey, stored under HKLM\`system

Comment: Sounds about right, syskey was added to stop the first NTLM dump tools.